# Developing SharePoint App Causes a new url to generated each time I deploy

Tags: social-networking, sharepoint-apps

I am developing a SharePoint app that communicates with social feeds such as Twitter, Facebook (the user has to sign in ofcourse through the App using OAUTH).  My problem is that everytime I deploy the app (using VS) it generates a new url and I need to keep registering this url with the community sites (Twitter, Facebook).  Is there another way to overcome this problem.

Comment: I have the same question. Were you ever able to figure out what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are talking about the App Web wich is created every time the application is deployed (url has a form like that `https://prefix-id.tenantdomain.tld/pathOfWebItHasBeenDeployedTo`)
This is by design and [here is some documentation about it](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2012/09/sharepoint-apps-working-with-app-web.html)
Then I guess the problem is because you're using OAuth implicit flow which requires url not to change over time.  Unfortunately this is a by design limitation, to work around that you'd have to transtion to a provider hosted application. (therefore hosting it on your own server with a fixed url)